# Interpreting a MySQL nested SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am not a MySQL expert by any means, but after reading the documentation for the `SELECT` statement, I did not find an answer to my problem.

I have this statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)=x.c FROM someTable, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) c 
     FROM someTable 
     WHERE firstId <= secondId) x;
```

And I'm trying to figure out what the `x.c` means in the context of the query? Specifically, what is with the `x` that seems to be hanging out there?

I interpret the nested `SELECT` as `SELECT COUNT(*) as c`, making an alias for the row count as `c`, is that what the `x` is as well? What would it be an alias for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` is a table alias -  a name for the nested `SELECT` statement in parentheses.

```
COUNT(*)=x.c
```

Is a boolean condition that the total row count of `someTable` be equal to the row count of `someTable` where `firstId <= secondId`

`x.c` is the column name for the count returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

They name the subquery "x" and in the subquery they name the count(*) "c". So "x.c" means the count returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` is an alias to the subquery - you will note that there is an `x` just after the subquery, denoting the alias name for it.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is an alias for the table `(SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM someTable WHERE firstId <= secondId)`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL requires that table subqueries have a unique alias. You'll notice there's an `x` at the end of the subquery, which makes the sub queries results appear as coming from table `x`.

In this case, `x.c` in the outer query means to refer to field `c` (the count result) in the aliased table `x`, which is the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

X is an alias for joined someTable and the select you joined someTable with. I guess so :D

I guessed wrong, guys over me are right :P